# Spring MVC ExceptionHandler for restful and normal

Tags: spring-mvc, exception, spring-rest

I want to handle exception for both normal and rest/ajax requests. Here is my code,

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleCustomException(Exception ex) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error");
        model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getMessage());
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        sw.toString();
        model.addObject("errTrace", sw);
        return model;

    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleAjaxException(Exception ex) {
        JSONObject model = new JSONObject();
        model.put("status", "error");
        model.put("errMsg", ex.getMessage());
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        sw.toString();
        model.put("errTrace", sw);

        return model.toString();
    }
}
```

This will give me an error as I cant have @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) twice. So what could be the solution?

Answer (score 5):

see the configuration of @ControllerAdvice:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html

So you can create two classes(error handlers) and specify annotations/basePackages/assignibaleTypes

For example for REST(ajax) use @RestController annotation for your controllers and you can handle errors like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleAjaxException(Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

for other cases it can be error handler with annotation

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
```

Comment: I have annotated class with @Controller and some methods have @ ResponseBody and some are normal returning Model. I have used your example but always call annotation = Controller.class. I think just because I have used @ Controller for controller class ?!!

Comment: yes, your REST-methods should be in separate controller with annotation @RestController instead of @Controller(to make this solution working).

Answer (score 2):

This is global exception handler in spring mvc.this is called every time when exception found in your application.I think you to control only 404 exception with the help of web.xml.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView handleAllException(Throwable ex,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
        // Set Status
        response.setStatus(500);
        // Set View
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("500");
        model.addObject("navlabel", "");
        model.addObject("userActivity", new ArrayList<String>());
        // Set exception Message
        model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getMessage());
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This global one returns ModelAndView, this is ok for normal request like http://server/app/getCustomer and we set view name. But with ajax request in case of any error it should send error message as string so can be displayed with alert().

Comment: I think @ResponseBody will it convert to the json.Have you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create inner static class @RestControllerAdvice. Noot needed to create separated @RestController for this.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class BaseController {
private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseController.class);

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String handleException(Exception error, Model model) {
    logger.error("Error was: " + error.getMessage(), error);
    model.addAttribute("message", error.getMessage());
    model.addAttribute("stackTrace", error.getStackTrace());
    model.addAttribute("exception", error);
    return "error"; //return view
}

@RestControllerAdvice
public static class RestBaseController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestBaseController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String handleException(Exception error) {
        logger.error("Error was: " + error.getMessage(), error);

        return "error"; //return "error"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write two exception handler to handle both normal and rest/ajax requests exception. Here is sample code to illustrate the solution.

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
@Order(1)
class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler() {
        ....
    }   
}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
@Order(2)
class ExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError500(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("error");
        mav.addObject("error", "500");
        return mav;
    }
}
```